# maven compile failure. cannot access

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

i am acessing a class, which is part of the Elasticsearch server.
When i compile the code inside Eclipse, i have no problems. doing it in Maven i get an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project flume-ng-elasticsearch-sink: Compilation failure
[ERROR] \Eclipse\Workspace\flume\flume-ng-sinks\flume-ng-elasticsearch-sink\src\main\java\org\apache\flume\sink\elasticsearch\client\ElasticSearchTransportClient.java:[202,19] error: cannot access Level
```

My code is:

```
Settings.Builder settingsBuilder = Settings.builder()
    .put("cluster.name", clusterName);
```

The property "Level" is defined in a class from the Elasticsearch Project.
Code is available [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/settings/Settings.java).

Any idea, which might be wrong?

thanks,

Helmut

Comment: What versions are you using? Also, have you edited ElasticSearchTransportClient?

Comment: Java 1.8_144
ElasticSearch 6.1.0  

Yes, i have edited the ElasticSearchTransportClient.It needed to be rewritten to work with 6.1.  
When i compile it with Eclipse and do a "mvn install", i have a working Flume with ES 6.1.
But when i do a "mvn clean compile" or "mvn clean install", so that maven does the compile, i get the above error.
Looks like i am missing a reference to Log4J, but can't find the place in pom.xml to add.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.
In pom file of the project the dependency to Log4J had a scope of "test", so it was not available to the compile scope. 
Removed the scope test and all is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

## Compiler and Java version

In my case the problem was a combination of two things.

First, the Java version of the dependency (the class that "cannot access") was way ahead of that of the project I am building now (17 versus 11), so the compiler would not understand it.

Second, the compiler version in the project I am building was too old, so it would not complain correctly about the class file version. I upgraded the compiler plugin (from 2.2 to 3.10.1) and then it would complain about a class file too advanced for the Java version I was using.

After those two corrections, I moved forward to later errors.